# Error 'angular is not defined' while upgrading AngularJS1 component

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade, angular-upgrade

I'm trying to do upgrade components written in AngularJS1 to Angular6. I'm taking the approach of having the wrappers for all the existing AngularJS1 component by extending "**UpgradeComponent**" placed under the folder "`directive-wrappers`" in my example. I have written this application in my local and it works fine for 2 components `TestDirectiveWrapper` and `TestDirective2Wrapper`.

But when I include the third component `TestDirective3Wrapper`, while loading the application I get the console error as

```
angular.min.js:127 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.5/$injector/unpr?p0=testDirective3DirectiveProvider%20%3C-%20testDirective3Directive
    at angular.min.js:7
    at angular.min.js:46
    at Object.d [as get] (angular.min.js:43)
    at angular.min.js:46
    at Object.d [as get] (angular.min.js:43)
    at Function.push../node_modules/@angular/upgrade/fesm5/static.js.UpgradeHelper.getDirective (static.js:872)
    at new UpgradeHelper (static.js:869)
    at TestDirective3Wrapper.UpgradeComponent (static.js:1170)
    at new TestDirective3Wrapper (TestDirective3Wrapper.ts:9)
    at createClass (core.js:9296) "<app-root _nghost-c0="">"
```

[image]

To mimic the same application online I have created the same angularjs directives and its wrappers in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/upgradejs1), but here I'm getting a different error though.

[image]

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue and enable me to load all the 3 components?

Comment: where have you included angularjs file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a play with this, and I managed to [get it to work](https://stackblitz.com/edit/upgradejs1-ey43ot).

There were a few things missing.

1. You didn't actually include the AngularJS 1.x file.
2. You didn't import the original AngularJS app module file, or any of the directives.

Once I did those two things, it worked for me.

Here is the relevant code:

**In `app.module.ts`:**

```
import '../AngularJsApp/app.module'; // added

declare var angular: any; // added

angular
  .module('testApp')
  .directive('appRoot', downgradeComponent({ component: AppComponent }));
```

**In `AngularJsApp/app.module.js`:**

```
'use strict';

const angular = require('angular'); // added

// Define the `testApp` module
angular.module('testApp', []);

// added these 3 lines
require('./test-directive/test-directive.js');
require('./test-directive2/test-directive2.js');
require('./test-directive3/test-directive3.js');
```

Comment: I did the same changes listed by you here in my local, but I'm getting compilation exception as below: ERROR in ./src/AngularJsApp/app.module.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'angular' in 'C:\..\NG6Hybrid\src\AngularJsApp'
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

any thing I'm missing here?

Comment: @Krishnan Did you check out my working StackBlitz example linked in my answer and compare it to your local code? It is possible I made other changes I did not call out explicitly in my answer.

Comment: I did compared your changes with my code, but couldn't spot any differences. Even If I add any new component I get the same error "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider".. Looks like I'm missing something here...?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng6hybrid-xvu8bw

Comment: thanks, the issue is resolved, now I'm able to load the controllers using Upgrades - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng6hybrid-qzrovd

Comment: When I try to add some controllers, I get the same error message. I tried adding studentController and homePageController, but not able to load it. Any ideas why I'm facing this issue?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng6hybrid-c8h6uv

Comment: @Krishnan That is a separate question, so in future, ask a new question for follow up questions. That said, here is my best guess as to why that doesn't work. Using plain controllers like that outside of a directive is a very outdated pattern, even in AngularJS 1.x. I don't believe it is supported to upgrade controllers to Angular 2+, but I could be wrong. My understanding was you needed to have element based directives to upgrade them successfully. I would work on refactoring your AngularJS code first, then upgrading them. Good luck!

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply. actually my requirement is I don't want to touch my existing controllers, instead create a directive wrapper for the controller and do the upgrade.. let me know if it is possible with a example ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58468481/how-to-create-wrapper-directives-for-controller-in-angularjs